# 50 amp inlet box to transfer switch

Tags: transfer-switch

I have a Reliance 50amp transfer switch which I am connecting to a 50 amp inlet box. My understanding is that 6 awg copper wire should be run from the inlet box to the transfer switch. The question I have is does the ground wire also need to be 6 awg? I have seen examples where 6 awg was used for the conductors and the neutral, but 10 awg was used for the ground. Is this acceptable or should all 4 wires be 6 awg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [NEC Table 250.122](https://codes.iccsafe.org/s/ISEP2018/national-electrical-code-nec-solar-provisions/ISEP2018-NEC-Sec250.122), 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum is sufficient for a 25A - 60A circuit.